# Error for allocation proportion during stratified sampling in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to create a stratified sample from a dataset in SAS using the Proc SurveySelect statement. I am getting the error 'Sum of allocation proportion should be equal to 1'. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Please find below the code that I am using:

```
data Treatment;
set cashback4;
where CASHBACK=1;
run;

proc surveyselect data=cashback4
method=sys N=300000 out=sample_main;
strata Free_Card event event_lifestage edu_qual surrogate Zone CHANNEL /ALLOC=prop;  
RUN;

proc surveyselect data=treatment
method=sys N=50000 out=sample1;
strata Free_Card event event_lifestage edu_qual surrogate Zone CHANNEL/ALLOC=sample_main;  
RUN;
```

Sample_main is getting created but sample1 is not.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, verifiable and complete](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of code that causes this error.

Answer (score 0):

As @user667489 pointed out, you really should post the code you have tried, which would make answering the question much easier.

My guess is that you are using the `ALLOC=` option, where you specify the proportions to be used for each strata. These need to add up to 1 and will produce the error you're getting if they don't.